# Create a Table with auto width <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm going to try to explain myself. 
I would like to achieve this:

I need to create a table with 4 columns and many td (lines). 
But, I need the single lines to have automatic column width based on their content.

Normally, this is what happens with columns, the largest td (line) dictate the size of the column in which is contained:

[image]

Instead. I am trying to achieve this:

I want to still organise elements in a Table (columns) so that I can organise the content for ex. by alphabetic properties.
BUT I need the columns to look like this:

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: i dont think table can do this , can't you use div ?

Comment: a table always has equal column widths in all rows. To create your example with tables, you could simply create 5 tables - one for each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `display:inline` for the columns (`<td>`). A better alternative would be to use `<div>` and flexbox.

```css
td {
  border:2px solid red;
  display: inline;
}
td:nth-child(1) {
  background:yellow;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
  background:blue;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
  background:grey;
}
td:nth-child(4) {
  background:orange;
}
table {
  border:1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ant</td>
    <td>Bear</td>
    <td>Cat</td>
    <td>Dog</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you, I appreciate your help.